# My unbound (Menu) subform is appearing in datasheet

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, subform, datasheet

I use an unbound form as a Menu/Navigation for my application. The menu form has VBA "on click" events for the labels. That is it.

When I add it as a subform to a split-form that is bound to one of the tables, the "menu" subform displays as a sub-datasheet.

When I go to the datasheet view to remove the sub-datasheet the "Remove" button is greyed out.

I've checked the main form and the menu sub-form for Subdatasheet Expanded "NO" and Subdatasheet Height "0"

I know this is probably going to be something painfully obvious that I seem to be overlooking but I've been searching for a solution all morning.

Thanks, people.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your navigation form using design view? For example, here is my split form with the navigation form added, note that the navigation form is set to display Single Form.

[image: split form design view]

Here is the form displayed:

[image: split form normal view]

Comment: Thanks Remou, Yes I did add the form via Design View (I never thought you could add a form using VBA). I have "frmMenu" as a Single Form. I added images to my original question.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot reproduce the problem. If you want another eye on your form, can you upload it do dropbox or such like?

Comment: Remou, when you click the "+" on your datasheet do you get the Label from your subform? That is what is happening to me. I've even tried recreating a navigation form but that didn't work.